# PoweCMD ask when close and start location?

Tags: command-line

I have 2 questions about [PowerCMD](http://www.powercmd.com/) :

1. At the first time, when I closed PowerCMD it asked me to decide whether save all tabs or not. I have checked something like `Do not ask this again next time` and now I want to change this behavior but can't find where to configure.
2. I want that whenever click on `PowerCMD here` in context menu, PowerCMD will be launched with the current location in windows explorer. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. File - Preference - Show warning message when exit must be checked
2. Isn't this the default case? I just downloaded PowerCmd and tried it together with Directory Opus (which has this functionality for the default cmd.exe as well btw.) and it works fine. It also focuses the latest path leaving the previous paths open in other tabs.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't see `File - Preference - Show warning message when exit must be checked` @_@. Regarding point 2, when I launch a new instance it focuses on the last tab not the new one which just opened, how about yours ?